# In mozilla firefox, how do I dock the dom inspector to the bottom of the current tab?

Tags: firefox

In mozilla's firefox browser is it possible to dock the dom inspector to the bottom of the current browser tab? Similar to the internet explorer developer toolbar?

Answer (score 1):

No.  I would use [Firebug](http://getfirebug.com/), which can inspect the DOM (among other things) and docks by default.

Comment: Surely this is more of a comment.

Comment: @rice, I answered the actual question, "is it possible".

Comment: I have not found any way or button to dock the dom insepctor either and am already using the firebug suggestion. I am going to assume there is not a method to dock the dom inspector.

Comment: Yeah, that's true I guess. =)

Answer (score 1):

Every now and then, I fix DOM Inspector bugs.

As of this writing, there is no prepackaged way to achieve what you want here.  I also think it's safe to say that there are currently no plans from any active developer to add this feature, either.  Sorry.

The DOM Inspector does have its own browser pane at the bottom of its own window, though.  From the "View" menu in the DOM Inspector menubar, select "Browser".  SeaMonkey users also have the DOM Inspector available as a sidebar, but it's only possible to view one pane at a time (i.e., the document pane and the object pane are in a tabbed view.)  It can be installed in the sidebar from the DOM Inspector section in SeaMonkey preferences.